# Web Forms and SDK format of csproj

Tags: webforms, csproj

Is there any way how to convert legacy `Web Forms` project to a new `SDK csproj` format? Tried everything. Web app can be build but cannot be run. It always ends with errors like
*"Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"*

All I want is to switch nuget package references.

I just want to know if I'm doing something wrong or it is not possible.

**EDIT:**
It is not just about nuget references, I simple want to simplify whole csproj and "include all". I want to get rid of csproj merge hell when adding content.

Comment: You might want to review the answers on this again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Many of the benefits of the new SDK format come with the VS support of a new "project system" (what provides VS integration for the MSBuild C#/VB projects).
They do not support classic ASP.NET applications (MVC, WebForms) or Web Site projects.

Comment: Do you happen to have any reference you could cite to support your answer? Is this explicitly mentioned in official documentation, or is it just something you know?

Comment: I'm not sure it's documented per-se but at least the feature request has been open for 5 years - https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2670

Comment: @MartinUllrich If it is not possible why .Net Framework 4.8 mentioned as compatible framework in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Comment: It's a limitation of the "classic"/"legacy" ASP.NET Core tooling, not the SDK or MSBuild itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You can use a third party SDK solution such as this:

- https://github.com/CZEMacLeod/MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb

Which enables you to migrate legacy AspNet projects that rely on `System.Web` assemblies to work using the new SDK-style csproj structure, including the use of `PackageReference` elements and any other modern features.

To use the SDK, just follow the documentation and add the reference to the SDK at the top of the csproj file like this (the version is mandatory):

```xml
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb/4.0.81">
```

This will then automatically download the SDK from nuget.org and work seamlessly.

Comment: Considering the number of bugs and missing features with that community approach, any push of already frustrated developers to that can just add more pains.